# Map array of objects to single object

Tags: javascript

I have this array of objects:

```
[
  { bankName: { id: 1, name: 'SANTANDER' }, totalClients: 12 },
  { bankName: { id: 3, name: 'ESTADO' }, totalClients: 9 },
  { bankName: { id: 2, name: 'CHILE' }, totalClients: 8 }
]
```

how can i get this object?

```
{
  'SANTANDER': 12,
  'ESTADO': 9,
  'CHILE': 8
}
```

Comment: Why would you want to do that? And also share the code chunk that you made.

Comment: having conversion problems, i have no code yet...

Comment: Familiarize yourself with [how to access and process nested objects, arrays or JSON](/q/11922383/4642212) and how to [create objects](//developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer) and use the available [`Object`](//developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object#Static_methods) and [`Array`](//developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#Static_methods) methods (both static and on prototype).

Answer (score 4):

You can use [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to get the desired result.

```js
const arr = [
  { bankName: { id: 1, name: "SANTANDER" }, totalClients: 12 },
  { bankName: { id: 3, name: "ESTADO" }, totalClients: 9 },
  { bankName: { id: 2, name: "CHILE" }, totalClients: 8 },
];

const result = arr.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  acc[curr.bankName.name] = curr.totalClients;
  return acc;
}, {});

console.log(result);
```

**2)**

```js
const arr = [
  { bankName: { id: 1, name: "SANTANDER" }, totalClients: 12 },
  { bankName: { id: 3, name: "ESTADO" }, totalClients: 9 },
  { bankName: { id: 2, name: "CHILE" }, totalClients: 8 },
];

const result = arr.reduce((acc, { bankName: { name: key }, totalClients: value}) => {
    acc[key] = value;
    return acc;
  }, {});

console.log(result);
```